# jQuery add/remove class or toggle class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im just curious to know the best practice for either toggling a class or just adding and removing it during a mouseenter/mouseleave state using jquery. Both seem to work fine im just not to sure which is best to go with.

Thank you

```js
  $('#image1').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#image1').toggleClass('transform');
    $('#image1 .images-color-overlay').toggleClass('transparent');
    $('#image1 .images-text').toggleClass('show-images-text');
  });

  $('#image1').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#image1').toggleClass('transform show-images-text');
    $('#image1 .images-color-overlay').toggleClass('transparent');
    $('#image1 .images-text').toggleClass('show-images-text');
  });
```

```css
.images-color-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.images {
  width: 33.333%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#image1 {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1000x320");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.images-text {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: normal;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.show-images-text {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  bottom: 20px;
}
.transform {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  transform: scale(1.25);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.transparent {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
  <div id="image1">
    <div class="images-color-overlay">
      <p class="images-text">hidden-text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Rory's answer is very good. But as of using toggleClass vs add and remove, it depends on the initial state of your class and the desired outcome. Toggle will switch it on and off regardless of what you want. So you need to make sure there's no other code that toggles the class (and keep it changed). And make sure the initial state is always what you expect it to be. In the rare case that you can't make sure. Its better to use remove and add instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is technically fine, however you can shorten it to just use the `hover()` method, as the function you provide will be called for both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

You can also use the `this` reference in the function to save DOM accesses, and also cache the jQuery object created from `$(this)` in a variable for re-use. Try this:

```js
$('#image1').hover(function() {
  var $image = $(this).toggleClass('transform');
  $image.find('.images-color-overlay').toggleClass('transparent');
  $image.find('.images-text').toggleClass('show-images-text');
});
```

```css
.images-color-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.images {
  width: 33.333%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#image1 {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1000x320");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.images-text {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: normal;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.show-images-text {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  bottom: 20px;
}
.transform {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  transform: scale(1.25);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.transparent {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
  <div id="image1">
    <div class="images-color-overlay">
      <p class="images-text">hidden-text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks very much for this, very informative and helpful. Will use the hover function for this instead of mouse enter/leave and the variable is a nice idea to which will help shorten the code. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Well a lot of this style question get shot down here on SO, because it seems it comes down to preference.  But HERE is a way to do it all without javascript, only CSS, which some might consider more efficient.

```css
.images-color-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.images {
  width: 33.333%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#image1 {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1000x320");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.images-text {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: normal;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#image1:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  transform: scale(1.25);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

#image1:hover .images-text {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.images-color-overlay:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
  <div id="image1">
    <div class="images-color-overlay">
      <p class="images-text">hidden-text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, the only reason i didnt want to go down the full css route (which i would do for most things where possible) is because i will be using a jquery 'if' statement on the hover state to convert to a click state on mobile devices. I'm always worried of conflicts when using hover states through css and click states using jquery on the same element when going between different screen sizes. Thanks for this though works a treat.

Comment: I wouldn't say this kind of question gets shot down. CSS is always the best solution for this kind of issue, it's just a shame it doesn't fit the OPs requirements. +1 nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

The `toggleClass` is the bast practice in your case.

Internally it's also doing same thing if the class exist then remove it and if not then add it. See it yourself , goto this [github link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/classes.js) and search for `toggleClass`.

```
// Check each className given, space separated list
if (self.hasClass(className)) {
  self.removeClass(className);
} else {
  self.addClass(className);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your input much appreciated